# Adding array object to an array in a foreach loop if a condition is satisfied in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array like this.

```
$array = [
       0 =>[
           "name" => "John",
           "age" => "20",
           "class" => "first"
       ],
       1 => [
           "name" => "Doe",
            "age" => "22",
            "class" => "second"
       ],
       2 => [
            "name" => "Template",
            "age" => "30",
            "class" => "third"
        ],
    ];

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($arr["name"] == "Template") {
        $arr["result"] = ["maths" => "60", "English" => "20"];
        array_push($arr,$arr["result"]);
    }
}
```

I have tried several things like using `array_push($arr,$arr["result"])` but that still returns the array.
How can i loop through it to return something like this.

```
    2 => [
        "name" => "Template",
        "age" => "30",
        "class" => "third",
        "result"=> ["maths" => "60", "English" => "20"],
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make the loop by reference with `&`

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    if ($arr["name"] == "Template") {
        $arr["result"] = ["maths" => "60", "English" => "20"];
    }
}
```

This results in `var_dump($array);`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["class"]=>
    string(5) "first"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Doe"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["class"]=>
    string(6) "second"
  }
  [2]=>
  &array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Template"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["class"]=>
    string(5) "third"
    ["result"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["maths"]=>
      string(2) "60"
      ["English"]=>
      string(2) "20"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Another method is to make the array associative on name and directly access the correct subarray.

```
$array = array_column($array, null, "name");
$array["Template"]["result"] = ["maths" => "60", "English" => "20"];


var_dump($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/WFqfG

Just as with the loop method it requires unique names.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was just what i needed.

Answer (score 5):

You're very close, just change this one line:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
```

To this:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
```

And then remove the `array_push()`, as it's not needed. In the former, `$arr` is a copy of the subarray that gets discarded at the end of the loop iteration. In the latter, `$arr` is a pointer to the original subarray, so changes are maintained. See [PHP: References Explained](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) for details.

Comment: other way is use foreach ($array as $key => $arr) and then change value using $array[$key]

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a laravel tag, here is one way you could achieve it using laravel collections.

```
$array = collect($array)->map(function($item){
   if($item['name'] == "Template")
      $item['result'] = ["maths" => "60", "English" => "20"];
   return $item;
})->toArray();
```

`collect` method converts the array into a collection. `map` function will go over all elements of the array and using the callback function you can bring changes to the original collection. The changes are maintained. The `toArray` at the end is added assuming that the final data is required as an array. Without the, `toArray` it'd be a collection.

Edit: There was a laravel tag.